# Using javax.validation in GWT throws runtime error ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, validation, gwt

I'm using in GWT application the javax.validation.*
I added the dependencies to my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

But on runtime i'm getting ClassNotFoundException :

2012-03-20 09:46:12,253 WARN [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.c.t.c.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor [AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.java:91] Failed to classload type while reading annotation metadata. This is a non-fatal error, but certain annotation metadata may be unavailable.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
       at

Any ideas?

Comment: call mvn help:effective-pom and check if the validation-api is in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are actually several things you need for the validation framework to work.

You need the validation API.  It **seems** like you have that but you must remember that GWT needs the *source* of included files.

In order to get this to work you need to include both the API jar and API sources.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <classifier>sources</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Without this you'll get class not found exceptions for the validation API.

You also need to make sure that you've added the validation inclusion to your GWT module XML.

```
<inherits name="org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator" />
<replace-with
    class="com.google.gwt.sample.validation.client.SampleValidatorFactory">
    <when-type-is class="javax.validation.ValidatorFactory" />
</replace-with>
```

Further, you also need to include a validation engine of some sort.  You probably want hibernate-validation if you're following the GWT bean validation guide.

To validate an annotated object, you should use the API provided.

```
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;

/* ... snip ... */

//get validator factory using default bootstrap mechanism of the Validation library
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure().buildValidatorFactory();

//get a validator instance
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

//create new object
Person person = new Person();
person.setFirstName("Andrew");

//validate person object
Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> violations = validator.validate(person);

//should be one violation from lastName being null
assert violations.size() == 1;
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! It seems the right way.
But I wonder - we actually want (for now) only simple capabilities of the javax.validation - specifically Nullable and NotNull, and not yet use the full validation mechanism. Is this still the right way (use the hibernate validator)?
Moreover - I think I'm not sure how exactly these validation works - will I get compilation errors? run-time errors? Should I explicitly invoke some validator...?

Comment: I'm going to leave this here: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-validation/ .  But, seriously, either toolkit will work.  The validation engine works by scanning the annotations on a given class and then using that to run through the engine.  The same validation code seen here: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-validation/wiki/GWT_Validation_2_0 should get you on the right path.  I've updated my post to include the source code example.

Answer (score 1):

you must add one jar, with the validation implementation, such us hibernate-validation.